# Bypass Silent Switch with Local Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, alert, playback, mute

I'm building an alarm app and my only issue is having the alerts bypass the mute button. Now I did my research and didn't find anything useful a lot of people say it's not possible but I know it is. A lot of alarm clock apps and even Apple's stock clock app have this feature. I'm using iOS's local notifications to push the alert to the user. When the phone is not on silent it works fine. But when the phone is on silent I get the alert and a vibration but no sound. I would like the alert sound to play even when the phone is on mute because say someone creates an alert for the morning and they want to mute their phone so they don't get alerts from other applications waking them up in the middle of the night.

If you have any suggestions please let me know I haven't found anything useful, hopefully someone can put me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!